# How to use names as enum that are already used by vb.net as keyword

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums, keyword

I am implementing the show-message extension found on this blog: http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/05/03/keep-your-users-informed-with-asp-net-mvc/

the programmer makes clever reuse of his enum to build css attribuuts but in vb.net i run on something strange.

I need this class

```
Enum Messagetype
    Succes = 1
    Error = 2
    Notification = 3
End Enum
```

but visual studio keeps giving an error on the Error enum. Is there a prefix i can use to tell visual studio its ok to use error as enum ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could wrap reserved words in `[]` in VB.NET (the same as the `@` in C#):

```
Enum Messagetype
    Succes = 1
    [Error] = 2
    Notification = 3
End Enum
```

Comment: Thanks for the superfast reply :)

Comment: how do I do that in visual studio C++?